# How to setup a global container (C++03)?

Tags: c++, global-variables, containers, c++03

I want to define a global container (C++03), and here's an example code I tried, which does not work.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<string> Aries;
Aries.push_back("Taurus");    // line 6

int main() {}
```

Compile error:

```
prog.cpp:6:1: error: 'Aries' does not name a type
```

It seems I can define an empty global vector, but cannot fill it up. Looks like in C++03, I cannot specify an initializer either, such as:

```
vector<string> Aries = { "Taurus" };
```

Have I made a mistake here, or how do I get around this problem?

I tried searching on StackOverflow to see if this has been answered before, but only came across these posts: [global objects in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395102/global-objects-in-c), [Defining global constant in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268749/defining-global-constant-in-c), which did not help answer this.

Comment: The issue is that you can't have code outside any function. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a neat workaround to "initialize" C++03 global STL containers (and indeed to execute code "globally" before `main()`). This uses the comma operator. See example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<string> Aries;

// dummy variable initialization to setup the vector.
// using comma operator here to cause code execution in global scope.
int dummy = (Aries.push_back("Taurus"), Aries.push_back("Leo"), 0);

int main() {
    cout << Aries.at(0) << endl;
    cout << Aries.at(1) << endl;
}
```

Output

```
Taurus
Leo
```

The only real problem, if you can call it that, is the extra global variable.

Comment: I'm amazed, yet terrified with this solution. Have an upvote ;)

Comment: @milleniumbug Thanks for the upvote, but why are you terrified? ;)

Comment: IMHO it's not obvious to everyone and borders on obfuscation. I would put a comment before it to explain the trick.

Comment: And, for the global variable problem - you can declare it static to avoid external linkage, or wrap it around namespace to avoid polluting global scope.

Comment: @milleniumbug Ah, good point about documenting it. Let me edit the answer to include that.

Answer (score 10):

While declarations and initializations outside of a function (such as `main`) are no problems, you cannot have code outside of functions. You either need to set the value right at the initialization (as in C++11), or fill your global object in main:

```
std::vector<string> Aries;

/* ... */

int main() {
    Aries.push_back("Taurus");
    /* ... */
}
```

### Other ways (without populating the vector in main)

#### Single values

There are other ways which don't need `.push_back` or other code in the main. For example, if `Aries` shall contain only one item, you can use `std::vector<T>::vector(size_t s, T t)` with `s == 1` and `t == "Taurus"`:

```
std::vector<string> Aries(1, "Taurus");

/* ... */

int main() { /* ... */ }
```

If you need the same value several time you can simply adjust `s`.

#### Multiple distinct value

Now this gets a little bit trickier. You want to populate the `vector` by using a suitable constructor. `std::vector<T>` provides four different constructors in C++03:

1. `std::vector<T>::vector()`
2. `std::vector<T>::vector(size_t, T = T())`
3. `template <class InputIt> std::vector<T>::vector(InputIt, InputIt)`
4. `std::vector<T>::vector(const vector&)`
   Note that all of them actually take an allocator as additional last parameter, but this is not of our concern.

We can forget about `std::vector<T>::vector()`, since we want to fill the vector with values, and also `std::vector<T>::vector(size_t, T)` doesn't fit, since we want *distinct* values. What's left is the templated constructor and the copy constructor. The following example shows how to use the templated constructor:

```
std::string const values[] = {"Taurus", "Ares", "Testos"};

template <class T, size_t N>
T* begin(T (&array)[N]){ // this is already in C++11, very helpful 
    return array;
}
template <class T, size_t N>
T* end(T (&array)[N]){
    return array+N;
}

std::vector<std::string> Aries(begin(values), end(values));
```

Note that `begin` and `end` aren't necessary - we could simple use `Aries(values, values+3)`. However, things tend to change, and often you add a value or remove one. If you forget to change the offset `3` you would either forget an entry or cross borders of `values`.

However, this solution introduces a new global variable, which aren't that nice. Lets take a step back. We needed `values` since we wanted to use `std::vector<T>::vector(InputIt, InputIt)`, which needs a valid range. And the range must be known at the time we use the constructor, so it needs to be global. Curses! But behold: our toolbox still contains one constructor, the copy constructor. In order to use it we create an additional function:

```
namespace {
    std::vector<std::string> initializer(){
        const std::string dummy_array[] = {"Taurus", "Ares", "Testos"};
        return std::vector<std::string>(begin(dummy_array), end(dummy_array));
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> Aries(initializer());
```

This example uses both copy constructor and range constructor. You could also create a temporary vector and use `std::vector<T>::push_back` to populate it in the function.

Comment: What, not bothering to show how to set the value right at initialization in C++03?  It's easily done...

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, for a single value one could just use `std::vector<T>::vector(size_t, T)`, but for several values we would have to use `std::vector<T>::vector(InputIt, InputIt)` and thus an additional `const std::string []` or am I mistaken? `std::vector<T>::vector(const &vector)` would be possible with a little helper function.

Comment: I always go straight to the helper function in C++03: easy to understand, and handles all cases.

Answer (score 5):

My experience is that this "amazing, yet terrifying" (hat tip) solution is unpredictable.  Your initialization runs at load time.  You have no guarantee as to load ORDER.  So  everything that uses that container must be either in the same module, or somehow guarantee that the module is loaded before they access the container.  Otherwise, the container constructor has not run, yet your code happily calls its accessors.

When it goes wrong, it goes very wrong, and the error is compiler, platform, and phase of the moon dependent - in all cases giving not the remotest clue as to what went south.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the issue. However, this isn't specific to this solution.

Comment: BTW: The best solution to "static initialization order fiasco" is to stop using global objects with extern linkage when unnecessary.

Comment: You do have a good point and I am aware of the static initialization order fiasco. However, a solution is unsafe in 90% cases doesn't mean it should not be used in the remaining 10% cases when it is safe. Given a choice between a "always safe" solution that doesn't solve the problem at hand, and a solution that's safe only 10% of the time, but solves the current problem, it is quite clear what one should do. I know you don't mean to say "never do this", but might as well post this comment for clarity of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

And just for completeness, this solution uses iterator pair constructor and plain old array initializer.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string contents[] = {"Taurus", "Leo"};
vector<string> Aries(contents, contents + sizeof contents/sizeof contents[0]);

int main() {
    cout << Aries.at(0) << endl;
    cout << Aries.at(1) << endl;
}
```

This may be clearer, yet it calls more copy constructors.

Comment: +1: Didn't notice your answer before I edited mine because of [Mooning Duck's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899866/how-to-setup-a-global-container-c03/13899893#comment21058202_13899893). That could have saved me some minutes.